# fortran library for sparse matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, fortran, multiplication, sparse-matrix

I have a large matrix which I have stored in the following format, given the matrix A;

A =

```
 1   0    3
 5   1    -2
 0   0    7
```

3 vectors;

NVPN = [1 3 4 7] - I arbitrarily put a 1 in the first column, then from the second onwards it is a cumulatively summing the number of non-zero elements per column.

NNVI = [1 2 2 1 2 3] - row index of each non-zero element.

CONT = [1 5 1 3 -2 7] - value of each non-zero element.

I now need to perform matrix*matrix multiplication and matrix*vector multiplication. Does anyone know if the are any FORTRAN libraries, which I can amend to fit my problem, to do this above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your NVPN calculations do not make sense to me. How does 1+5+0=3? Or 0+1+0=4 or 3-2+7=7?

Comment: ok, it's 3 because there are 2 elements in the first column, so it is 3-1 = 2

Comment: Another example: A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 0 9]. NVPN would be [1 4 6 9]

Comment: Oops, it helps when I read. "Number of elements" != "value of elements", go figure.

Comment: No problem, I was thinking of writing a algorithm myself to do it, but not sure how much coding it will entail. Any idea?

Comment: I would think it would not be difficult to code that up at all. I'm not familiar with a lot of Fortran libraries, but these sorts of algorithms are not too tricky, so if it were my call, I'd just write it myself.

Comment: This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328482/fortran-90-95-library-for-sparse-matrices) Q&A may be of interest.  I think, though, that to use an off-the-shelf library you'll have to use one of the well-established sparse matrix representations such as CSC.

Comment: http://physics.jacobs-university.de/theine/research/splas/

Answer (score 0):

The MATMUL function allows you to perform matrix products, which is defined in the section 13.7.70 of the FORTRAN 90 [standard](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1601-N1650/N1601.pdf.gz). See also: [GCC reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MATMUL.html).

---

There is already a topic on sparse matrix libraries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328482/fortran-90-95-library-for-sparse-matrices).

Comment: That is for full matrices though, mine are sparse!

Comment: Do you know the BLAS library? I don’t know it, but I think it may be your solution.